# Sorting .txt file lines adds an incorrect line

Tags: python, sorting

So the issue is that when I run the leaderboard code it outputs some of the leaderboard correctly but then adds an incorrect line.

I have tried deleting the contents of the txt file, that didn't work.

```py
def save():
    global totalone,totaltwo,name1,name2,rounds
    file=open("scores.txt","a")
    if totalone < totaltwo:
        #name2 V name1 | totaltwo
        file.write(f"Scored {totaltwo} | Winner:{name2} V {name1} | played 0 H2H rounds\r")
    elif totaltwo < totalone:
        #name1 V name2 | totalone
        file.write(f"Scored {totalone} | Winner:{name1} V {name2} | Played 0 H2H rounds\r")
    else:
        #name1 V name2 | Tied | rounds
        if totalone < totaltwo:
            file.write(f"Scored {totalone} | Winner:{name1} V {name2} | Tied | Played {rounds} H2H rounds\r")
        elif totaltwo < totalone:
            file.write(f"Scored {totaltwo} | Winner:{name2} V {name1} | Tied | Played {rounds} H2H rounds\r")

    file.close()
def leaderboard():
    file=open("scores.txt","r")
    data=file.readlines()
    data.sort(reverse=True)
    x = 0
    for i in range(len(data)):
        print((data[i].strip()))
        x += 1
        if x == 5:
            break
    file.close()
```

The result shows me an unordered list.

```
Scored 20 | Winner:John V Kennedy | Played 0 H2H rounds  
Scored 40 | Winner:John V Kennedy | Played 0 H2H rounds  
Scored 10 | Winner:John V Kennedy | Played 0 H2H rounds  
Scored 80 | Winner:John V Kennedy | Played 0 H2H rounds
```

I would like them to be displayed like so:

```
Scored 80 | Winner:John V Kennedy | Played 0 H2H rounds  
Scored 40 | Winner:John V Kennedy | Played 0 H2H rounds 
Scored 20 | Winner:John V Kennedy | Played 0 H2H rounds  
Scored 10 | Winner:John V Kennedy | Played 0 H2H rounds
```

Comment: Why did you remove your expected results? They looked useful.

Comment: They weren't useful, just trying to make it harder for people to cheat by searching me online.

Comment: They [are still online](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56456951/revisions) in the revision history.

Comment: "Cheat" how? Is this homework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See @mkrieger1's solution for a real correct solution (actually sorting based on concrete values before formatting).

For a quick and kind of dirty solution, just replace your `data.sort(...)` with this:

```py
data.sort(reverse=True, key=lambda line: int(line.split()[1]))
```

What this does is tells the sort to use the value between the first and second space (which happens to be the score), and casting it to an int (so the sort is numeric and not alphabetical)

**Clarification:**

This is a terribly bad practice, because it may break if you change your line format (which has nothing to do with how the leader-board should be sorted, it's just is only related to display).

So, again, as far as software engineering goes, this is not a good practice. Just quick and works.

Answer (score 2):

```
data=file.readlines()
data.sort(reverse=True)
```

This sorts the lines alphabetically, so

```
Scored 7…
Scored 5…
Scored 4…
```

is "correct".

You need to sort based on the numeric score (the `totalone` or `totaltwo` variable) *before* formatting the output lines.

Comment: How do I sort by the numerical value?